# Error al convertir fecha con moment.js

Tags: javascript

Tengo un error un poco extraño. Estoy convirtiendo la fecha obtenida desde un datepicker con moment.js, pero este me devuelve el resultado con el mes equivocado.

Este es el resultado que me muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el codigo que utilizo en esta parte:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

  this.buscarForm = this.fb.group({
    fecha: ['', Validators.required]
  })
}

BuscaFecha(){

  const { fecha } = this.buscarForm.value
  const fechaM = moment(fecha).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

  console.log("Fecha normal: ", fecha)
  console.log("Fecha moment: ", fechaM)

}
```

La fecha normal la obtengo con un datepicker desde un Form y por alguna razon cuando la transformo  con moment.js el mes se aumenta en 1.

Como podria arreglar este error? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: El month de moment va [desde 0-11](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/02-get-set/12-month/), por tanto si le pasas `month: 7` lo tomará como agosto (mes 8). Asegúrate de restarle 1 al mes de `fecha` antes de pasarlo al constructor `moment`.

Comment: No había tomado eso en cuenta. Gracias!

Comment: No es el `month` de Moment, en realidad es de Javascript. El valor de meses en Javascript está en el rango 0 al 11 (inclusivos). Saludos